# Passing parameters to function pointer

Tags: c++

I am trying to pass parameters to a function pointer being passed as a parameter.

Code:

```
void Test(wchar_t* a, wchar_t* b)
{
    // ...
}

void Test2(void(*Func)(wchar_t*, wchar_t*))
{
    // ...
}

int main()
{
    Test2(Test(L"Hello", L"Testing"));
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting this error:

> argument of type "void" is incompatible with parameter of type "void (*)(wchar_t *, wchar_t *)"

How do I fix this to accomplish what I'm trying to achieve?

Edit: Sorry for not being clear. What I'm actually trying to accomplish is inject a function into a child process and pass two parameters (wchar_t*, wchar_t*) so I can use them. But the main function can either be void or int argc, char** argv. So I accomplished what I'm trying to achieve by simply using global variables

Comment: A lambda might suffice depending on what you want to do.

Comment: What exactly *is* it that you're trying to achieve? Your code is, as you've noticed, not valid C so it's not a useful demonstration of your intent.

Comment: πάντα ῥεῖ's answer is what I'm trying to achieve but I want a different way to do it like in C++ with templates

Answer (score 7):

You probably want to have something like

```
void Test2(void(*Func)(wchar_t*, wchar_t*),wchar_t* x, wchar_t* y)
{
    (*Func)(x,y);
}

int main()
{
    Test2(Test,L"Hello", L"Testing");
    return 0;
}
```

instead.

---

As for your comment

> How do i do this in C++ with templates?

I could think of

```
template<typename Param>
void Test2(void(*Func)(Param, Param), Param x, Param y) {
    (*Func)(x,y);
}

void Test(wchar_t* a, wchar_t* b);

int main() {
    Test2(Test,L"Hello", L"Testing");
    return 0;
}
```

This should just work fine.

Comment: your answer is what I'm trying to achieve. How do i do this in C++ with templates?

Comment: @user1304765 Updated my answer. Still not sure what you actually want.

Comment: Yea its actually a bit more complicated. I have one function that injects code (a function) into a child process so it has this parameter: int(*Main)(wchar_t*, wchar_t*). The Main function that I'm passing to it calls a function that takes two wchar_t*.

Comment: @user1304765 Well, I don't see so much need for a template function then. I hope your _child process_ is a thread actually though. You cannot change the signature of _`main()`_ and pass arbitrary parameter types.

Comment: Right, but it can be void. So then how do I get the two parameters passed?

Comment: @user1304765 _"Right, but it can be void."_ I don't get what you're actually asking for?

Comment: Nvm I figured it out. I'll just use global vars and make a function to change them when I need to. That way I can just pass main as void and I'll be able to use those 2 variables(wchar_t*, wchar_t*) in my child proces.

Comment: @user1304765 Calling `main` inside your program is not a good idea. In fact it's forbidden by the standard (See section 3.6.1). If this is a mis-communication, groovy, but if not I recommend a re-think.

Comment: im not calling main inside my main program though, im replacing a main function by injection in my child process then starting it.

Comment: @user1304765 I don't know if you can do that. Never tried. I wouldn't mess with `main`; the runtime expects `main` to look and behave a particular way under pain of undefined behaviour. In other words, it may look like it works until it suddenly doesn't. Instead give a plain old `main` that calls your injected function a try.

Comment: New question: have you given any thought to how you planning to get those global variables from one process to the other?

Comment: @user4581301 yes, I'll be able to access the variables. I've done this before.

Answer (score 0):

There are more than one way to fix tihs issue, however, let me just try to show why this error is occuring.

Every function has a type of value associated with it. This means, that every function evaluates to a value of some type. This is indicated by its return value.

For example:

```
int foo(/*whatever*/);
```

evaluates to an int. So `foo(/*whatever*/)` can be used anywhere an `int` is expected. For example like `int a = b + foo(/*whatever*/)`.

Simlarly `float bar(/*whatever*/);` evaluates to a `float`, hence `bar(/*whatever*/)` can be used anywhere a float is expected. For example like `float a = b + bar(/*whatever*/)`.

A function that returns `void` like `void foobar(/*whatever*/)` however, evaluates to `void` and *cannot* be used where a value of some type (say int, float, etc) is expected.

Now coming to code. This line in your `main` function has the issue:

```
int main()
{
    Test2(Test(L"Hello", L"Testing")); /* Issue here */
    return 0;
}
```

Here you are passing `Test(L"Hello", L"Testing")` as the argument to `Test2`. Now remember, that `Test(/*whatever*/)`, evaluates to a `void` because `Test` returns a void.

So what you are doing in that line is something like

```
Test2(/*something that evaluates to a void*/);
```

However, `Test2` expectes a `void (*)(wchar_t*, wchar_t*)`, which is a `pointer to a function that returns void`, which is different from `void`.

So what is happening, is that the compiler is seeing that you are passing a `void` in a place where a `void (*) (wchar_t*, wchar_t*)` is expected, so it is correctly indicating that error.

There can be different ways to solve this issue which are mentioned in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to use C++ templates?

Of course, you can do that using C++ templates as it follows:

```
#include<utility>

// ...

template<typename F, typename... A>
void Test2(F &&f, A&&... a)
{
    std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<A>(a)...);
    // ...
}

// ...

Test2(Test, L"Hello", L"Testing");
```

But you don't need them to do what you are trying to do.
@πάνταῥεῖ has already explained why in its answer.